# What capability allows someone to change a page's/post's author?

Tags: author, capabilities

I know that by default that administrators and editors can change the author of a page/post, but those with an author role can't. What role capability allows this?

Is there a way to give this capability to an author without also giving them the ability to edit other users posts/pages?

Answer (score 1):

The capability that controls setting the author would be [`edit_others_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#edit_others_posts). Giving this capability to Authors would make it possible for them to edit other users posts/pages. You would need to be a bit more specific about what you are trying to accomplish for any further advice.

There aren't any capabilities specific to just controlling the editing of the post/page author, but you could add your own capability to do such a thing.

Comment: WP doesn't have the concept of groups and doesn't allow you to let X authors work on a single item. So I was looking to give them the option to hand off a page/post to someone else. As admin I can easily do this, but it seems that I'd have to give authors added capabilities in order to do the same, and at the same time I don't want them to have access to edit every page/post in the system. If `edit_others_posts` is the only capability that will do this then I guess they're out of luck.