# Allow users to set a post author

Tags: capabilities, user-roles

I have a website owned by myself that allows people to submit work for us to publish.

I have a team of staff who need to create posts..etc
I have assigned users the author role which allows them to create posts but doesnt allow them to set a post author. I have tried setting them to editors but this doesnt work either.

Obviously i do not want staff to have full admin access so i am trying to control this.

I am using the capability manager enhanced plugin to help me control roles.

Comment: Editor role can change post author. You should check if this box isn't just hidden (top right corner, Screen Options).

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/202075/what-capability-allows-someone-to-change-a-pages-posts-author

Answer (score 2):

The `edit_others_posts` capability should allow users to set the author of a post.

At first glance you might reply that you don't want your authors to be able to edit one another's posts.  The difference in ability is very subtle though: writing a post and then assigning it to another user isn't much different from being able to write or edit that other user's posts.

Answer (score -1):

```
function add_theme_caps() {
   $role = get_role( 'author' );
   $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_posts' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_theme_caps');
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer, explaining why it will fix the problem.

Comment: If we set a role to edit others posts then that particular user can edit others posts in WordPress. The answer is clear I think.